# Send email using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp

I want to send email using asp.net, I have configured my SMTP service and added 127.0.0.1 as relay. I used to my home the application was success but I installed on the office it cannot send email why?

here is the C# code

```
MailMessage objemail = new MailMessage();
objemail.To.Add(new MailAddress("apthodisiac@gmail.com"));
objemail.From = new MailAddress(Request.Form["inputEmail"].ToString());
objemail.Subject = Request.Form["inputSubject"].ToString();
objemail.Body = "Dari: " + Request.Form["inputName"].ToString() + "\n\n" +
                "Phone: " + Request.Form["inputPhone"].ToString() + "\n\n" +
                Request.Form["inputMsg"].ToString();
objemail.IsBodyHtml = true;
objemail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
objSmtpClient.Send(objemail);
```

here is the web.config configuration

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network host="127.0.0.1" port="25" userName="yyyy" password="xxxxx" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

My office use proxy, is that the problem I cannot send email? please advice

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: Do some simple logging by wrapping this in a try/catch and writing the exception details to a txt file. Otherwise, it could be a bunch of things.

Comment: No error but I did not received the email

Answer (score 0):

May be **port number** is wrong try with port number `"587"` something as shown below:

```
private void SendEmail(string from, string to, string subject, string body)
    {
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(from), new MailAddress(to));

      mail.Subject = subject;
      mail.Body = body; 

      SmtpClient smtpMail = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
      smtpMail.Port = 587;
      smtpMail.EnableSsl = true;
      smtpMail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx");
      // and then send the mail
      smtpMail.Send(mail);
    }
```

Comment: I used localhost as mail server not gmail

Comment: Then try this http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2010/01/27/testing-email-from-localhost-with-aspnet-without-smtp-server/

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
objSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true
```